# How to set version-script file in CMakeLists.txt file of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, cmake

I have a ndk project in Android Studio, and I want to control the exported symbols by this way:

```
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} "-Wl,--version-script=D:\\ProjectFolder\\export_symbols")
```

or

```
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} "-Wl,--version-script=export_symbols")
```

This export_symbols file is put together with CMakeLists.txt.
The problem is that the compiler would report an error during link and complain that:  'error: no such file or directory'.

So the question is how can I tell the compiler where my export_symbols file is? Any suggestion is welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}` before the file name.

```
set (CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS ${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} "-Wl,--version-script=" ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} "/export_symbols")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to do next:

1. Find you `add_library` command. E.g.:

   ```
   add_library( ${MY_LIBRARY_NAME} SHARED main.cpp )
   ```
2. And right after it add `set_target_properties` command:

   ```
   set_target_properties( ${MY_LIBRARY_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../your_version.script)
   ```

Here is short info about [LINK_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/LINK_DEPENDS.html).

Comment: It didn't work for me. The docs for LINK_DEPENDS say "This property is ignored by non-Makefile generators." which may be why as I'm using Ninja. Good to know for future Makefile projects though