# How to hide symbols export from the static LibXml2.a

Tags: c++, gcc, symbols, ld, libxml2

I'm building a shared lib with static link to the libxml2 use MSYS2/Mingw64.
The libxml2 was built by the default options using Makefile.

My lib can be built success but all libxml2 symbols are exported too.

CMakefiles.txt

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DNDEBUG -DLIBXML_STATIC)

...

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mylib
        ${MYLIB_DEP_DIR}/xml2/lib/libxml2.${LIB_STATIC_SUFFIX}
        ${MYLIB_DEP_DIR}/xz/lib/liblzma.${LIB_STATIC_SUFFIX}
        ${MYLIB_DEP_DIR}/zlib/lib/${LIBZ}.${LIB_STATIC_SUFFIX}
)
TARGET_LINK_OPTIONS(mylib
        PRIVATE -Wl,--no-whole-archive
        PRIVATE -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL
)

IF(WIN32)
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mylib -lwsock32 -lws2_32)
ENDIF()
```

It looks like the "exclude-libs,ALL" not effect, or should I hack the libxml2 source codes/build scripts?

Comment: I believe you want to set your symbols "local" within a version script. Use of that version script within CMAKE is explained in the top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755711/how-to-set-version-script-file-in-cmakelists-txt-file-of-android-studio